# How to restore SQL Server backup I taken it from a PC with Windows authentication to another PC which also uses Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups

I have taken a backup from a PC has localhost server with Windows authentication, and I want to restore this backup to another PC which has a localhost server with Windows authentication.

I tried to restore it from SQL Server Management Studio, but it does not appear like other `.bak` files I mean when you choose a backup file to restore all files with (.bak) extension will appear and as i noteced only backup files who created by same PC will apear, as I know this problem is because a connection string is  different from first PC to second PC.

Is there anyway to restore it?

And I don't want to make a script file, I need it as backup file, anyone help please.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't appear like other .bak files? Is it not a .bak?

Comment: Please edit your question with the results of [RESTORE HEADERONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql) and [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql) on yuor backup file, as well as the actual filename and how you created that backup.  Include the version and edition of BOTH sql servers, the source and the target.

Comment: "it does not appear like other .bak files, as I know this problem is because a connection string is different from first PC to second PC" makes absolutely no sense. You should try explaining the issue rather than coming up with theories about it.

Comment: I edited my question , i hope it's will be clearly

Comment: If I understand correctly.... you didn't copy the backup file over? Go look in the folder that the restore command looks in. Your file isn't in there - you need to copy it over from the other machine.